# Using card layout, cards not swapping?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, cardlayout

I want to keep my Controller panel as type JPanel as I will be incorporating into a tab later, I want to swap between Main and NextPage using buttons on those specific screens, I don't want to have consistent buttons on the bottom for both screens that switch between cards(i.e I don't want to have add & back to be appearing on both screens), I am trying to get the add button in Main to go to NextPage and back button in NextPage to go to Main. This is what I have so far:

For Controller:

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Controller extends JPanel {

    private static Controller instance = new Controller();

    JPanel cards;
    Main mainPanel;
    NextPage nextPage;

    public Controller() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setSize(810, 510);
        cards = new JPanel(new CardLayout());

        mainPanel = new Main();
        nextPage = new NextPage();
        cards.add(mainPanel, "Main");
        cards.add(nextPage, "Next");
        add(cards);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MainPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Controller con = new Controller();
        frame.getContentPane().add(con);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }


    public void changeCard(String card) {
        CardLayout cl = (CardLayout) (cards.getLayout());
        cl.show(cards, card);
    }

    public static Controller getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

For main:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JButton search, add, delete;
    private JTextField textField;

    public Main() {

        search = new JButton("Search");
        add = new JButton("Add");
        delete = new JButton("Delete");
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        add.addActionListener(this);
        delete.addActionListener(this);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel top = new JPanel();
        top.add(search);
        add(top, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel bottom = new JPanel();
        bottom.add(add);
        bottom.add(delete);
        add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 500);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == add) {
            Controller.getInstance().changeCard("Next");
        } else if (e.getSource() == delete) {
           System.out.println("do something");
        }
    }

}
```

For NextPage:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NextPage extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private JButton back;
    private JTextField textField;

    public NextPage() {
        back = new JButton("Back");
        textField = new JTextField(20);
        back.addActionListener(this);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(back);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(400, 500);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == back) {
            Controller.getInstance().changeCard("Next");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `private static Controller instance = new Controller();`  Remove the `static` then figure out how to use a method of an instance and this problem will likely solve itself.  I suspect you are getting a different `Controller` instance to the one that you expect..

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Card Layout Actions](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/01/card-layout-actions/).

It is an extension of CardLayout that provides you with Previous/Next buttons that you can easily add to a panel separate from the CardLayout.